# Map reduce mongodb javascript IGNORE NULL values in this

Tags: javascript, mongodb, mapreduce

I'm not sure how, but I'd like to continue on when `this.tag_list` is null

```
var mapFunc3 = function(){
   var tags = this.tag_list.split(',');
   for (i in tags) {
     emit(tags[i], 1);
   }
}

var reducFunc3 = function(key, values){
    var count = 0;
    for( i in values){
      count += values[i];
    }
    return count;
}

db.names.mapReduce(
    mapFunc3,
    reducFunc3,
    {out: "mr_3"}
)
```

The error I get is:

```
"errmsg" : "MapReduce internal error :: caused by :: TypeError: this.tag_list is null :\n@:2:5\n",
        "code" : 139,
        "codeName" : "JSInterpreterFailure"
}
```

Comment: Make `mapFunc3 ` as `arrow function` and try.

Answer (score 1):

So instead of changing the JavaScript, I changed the Mongodb query so that it did not map any null items:

```
db.names.mapReduce(
mapFunc3,
reducFunc3,
{
out: {merge: "mr_3"},
query: {"tag_list": {$ne: null}}
}
)
```